# Logout and header to page without cache

Tags: php, caching

So, I have the following logout script (as taken from php.net):

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION = array();

if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]
    );
}

session_destroy();
header(...); //See Below
?>
```

The website has a header that echos either a login form (when not logged in) or "Welcome, User" (when logged in).

I have tried:

```
header("location:http://example.com");
```

in my logout script but the website header echos "Welcome, User" still until the page is refreshed. It is seemingly loading from cache(?).

One way I have gotten around this is changing the line to:

```
header("location:http://example.com?a=".uniqid());
```

As much as this works, it looks ugly in the address bar.

Is there a way to achieve the redirect without loading from cache or changing the address bar to remove the `GET` variable?

**EDIT:** OK, so this is strange... When I have the Chrome Dev Tools open to check the header response, it works fine. As soon as I close the Dev Tools, the problem comes back. Really need some help with this people!

Comment: have you already tried `unset()`ting the session variables?

Comment: "It is seemingly loading from cache" --- why don't you check response headers and know for sure? Guessing - is a bad strategy when debugging.

Comment: have tried `unset()` with same outcome

Comment: @matt1985: let me teach you how to use google. (there is a search engine http://google.com - it was opened recently so you presumably haven't heard of it). So - it's a smart piece of software and you could ask it questions as if it was a real person!! I know, it sounds unbelievable. But let's try together - open google site and put "how to get response headers in chrome" request there. How do you think - will it help us or not? Oh, amazing!!! The first result answers the exact my question. Well, now I probably will ask less silly questions here.

Comment: @zerkms Wow... Sarcasm just helps everyone on a Q&A site, doesn't it! You would have noticed I deleted my comment before you managed to press 'add comment' on your "response" (obviously took you too long to type). I was in the process of getting the info you firstly requested when my dns server crashed. Will edit my question accordingly.